# Zend Framework, Doctrine Help needed

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I am following the tutorial from [Introducing Doctrine 1.2 Integration](http://www.zendcasts.com/introducing-doctrine-1-2-integration/2009/11/)

I have a doctrine.php that "bootstraps?" doctrine ... sorry I don't really fully understand the tutorial yet.

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/..'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);

$application->getBootstrap()->bootstrap('doctrine');
$config = $application->getOption('doctrine');

$cli = new Doctrine_Cli($config);
$cli->run($_SERVER['argv']);
```

when I try to run it via cmd,

```
php.exe doctrine.php
```

I got

```
D:\Projects\ZF\doctrine\application\scripts>php -f doctrine.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'LogicException' with message 'Passed array does not specify an existing static met
hod (class 'Doctrine' not found)' in D:\Projects\ZF\doctrine\application\Bootstrap.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Projects\ZF\doctrine\application\Bootstrap.php(7): spl_autoload_register(Array)
#1 D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(662): Bootstrap-
>_initDoctrine()
#2 D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Appli
cation_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_executeResource('doctrine')
#3 D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\BootstrapAbstract.php(579): Zend_Appli
cation_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->_bootstrap('doctrine')
#4 D:\Projects\ZF\doctrine\application\scripts\doctrine.php(25): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract->bootstrap
('doctrine')
#5 D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library\Zend\Loader.php(136): include('D:\Projects\ZF in D:\Projects\ZF\d
octrine\application\Bootstrap.php on line 0
```

**Update 1**

```
protected function _initDoctrine() {
    $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()
         ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
    spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));

    $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING, Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE);
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);

    $doctrineConfig = $this->getOption("doctrine");
    $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($doctrineConfig['dsn']);
    $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);
    return $conn;
}
```

under `sql\_autoload\_register()` I guess. I don't really get what `spl\_autoload\_register()` also ... even in php reference.

**Update 2**

my bootstrap.php

```
<?php
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap {
    protected function _initDoctrine() {
        $this->getApplication()->getAutoloader()
                ->pushAutoloader(array('Doctrine', 'autoload'));
        spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));

        $manager = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance();
        $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE, true);
        $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_MODEL_LOADING, Doctrine::MODEL_LOADING_CONSERVATIVE);
        $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);

        $doctrineConfig = $this->getOption("doctrine");
        Doctrine::loadModels($doctrineConfig['models_path']);

        $conn = Doctrine_Manager::connection($doctrineConfig['dsn'], 'Doctrine');
        $conn->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_USE_NATIVE_ENUM, true);
        return $conn;
    }
}
```

I guess the thing thats not working is Zend does not seem to autoload the Doctrine class. which its supposed to because I already have registered the Doctrine namespace in config.ini

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine"
```

Does this mean Zend shld autoload Doctrine classes?

as for where Doctrine is stored, i have pointed to it inside PHP's include path.

> include_path =
>   ".;c:\php\includes;D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library;D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine121sandbox\lib"

I noted that if in `_initDoctrine()`, I require Doctrine manually it works.

```
require_once 'D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine121sandbox\lib\Doctrine.php';
```

has it got something to do with windows path (\ as separator)

Comment: Have you ever been able to solve this problem?

Comment: not actually, i guess a temporary fix was to put doctrine library inside the project library folder. it seems putting doctrine in a folder and including that folder in php.ini does not work for me. i am using windows 7, wamp 2

Comment: Try using https://github.com/beberlei/zf-doctrine if you want to get up and running in no time. The easiest and most complete (though not free of bugs) solution to zend/doctrine integration that i've come across so far.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the rest of the Zend Framework stuff working without the use of Doctrine? If so, you have a bootstrap file that you use for that application. Assuming a default directory layout, if you have your doctrine.php in your scripts directory and your bootstrap.php in your application directory, you should be able to just do this to get your doctrine cli working in doctrine.php:

```
require dirname(__FILE__).'/../application/global.php';
// the config line below might be different based on how you have your
// doctrine config stuff set up
$cli = new Doctrine_Cli(Zend_Registry::get('doctrine_config'));
$cli->run($_SERVER['argv']);
```

In your bootstrap.php (or a file required by your bootstrap.php), your autoloader should be configured something like this:

```
// set up your include path here
set_include_path(dirname(__FILE__).'/../library/zendframework'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/../library/doctrine'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/models'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/models/generated'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/business'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/business/exceptions'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/business/util'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . dirname(__FILE__).'/business/validators'
. PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());
require 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';

$loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$loader->suppressNotFoundWarnings(false);
$loader->setFallbackAutoloader(true);
```

Post here if this doesn't work. We had a bunch of issues setting this up in the beginning with Zend Framework's autoloader.

Comment: yes, i have rest of ZF working. but what is global.php? it seems like it pointing to the code from Bootstrap.php _initDoctrine() - refer to update 1

Comment: Oops. Forgot to mention that. What we do is that we have a bootstrap.php and on the first line of that file, we require our global.php (in the same location as bootstrap.php). Almost all of our logic that is independent of the MVC stuff is on global.php. This is so other code can use global to setup the autoloader, for example. The MVC stuff is in bootstrap.php (stuff like: Zend_Layout::startMvc(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts') and Zend_Controller_Front::run(dirname(__FILE__).'/controllers'))..

Comment: it seems it cannot find/autoload the Doctrine class. i have autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Doctrine" in application.ini already. and i am using Doctrine 1.2 does it makes any difference?

Comment: i also noticed that if i put the doctrine library inside my library folder in my project rather than in a shared folder and include that in php.ini, it will work.

Comment: So how are you including the files related to doctrine? Are you adding the doctrine directory to the include path? Are you using an absolute or relative path? Can you post that code?

Comment: i am doing it in php.ini include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\ZendFramework\library;**D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\Doctrine121sandbox\lib**"

Comment: I've added the include path to the code in my answer. Are you using the Zend Autoloader in your bootstrap file?

Answer (score 0):

I did face the same problem and got over it successfully 
what you need to do is change this

```
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, true);
```

to

```
    $manager->setAttribute(Doctrine::ATTR_AUTOLOAD_TABLE_CLASSES, false);
```

and i did remove this line also

```
  spl_autoload_register(array('Doctrine', 'modelsAutoload'));
```

I had reported these errors in the same [zendcasts forums](http://www.zendcasts.com/forum/post/440/#p440)
these steps helped  me to work with doctrine as expected :)